# Table display missing from Html Report generated by protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Tags: html, protractor, jasmine2.0

When I run my test using protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter for generating html report, my report gets created however with non-tabulated format:

Report

Summary

Total specs tested: 1
Total failed: 0
angularjs homepage todo list (4 s)

✓should add a todo(4 s)
Toggle Configuration

How can I create a better report where it shows the table with all the results?

Here is my conf.js file:

```
 var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-  
 reporter');
 var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
 dest: 'report-screenshots'
 , filename: 'my-report.html'

 });

 exports.config = {

 directConnect: true, //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
 capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome'
 }
, framework: 'jasmine'
, specs: ['todo-spec.js']
, allScriptsTimeout: 180000
, getPageTimeout: 180000
, jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
},

// Setup the report before any tests start
beforeLaunch: function () {
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
}); 
},

// Close the report after all tests finish
afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
});
}
, onPrepare: function () {
var width = 1300;
var height = 1200;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
afterAll(function (done) {
    process.nextTick(done);
})
}
};
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`generates reports in the format you are expecting

I just checked and its generating in the below format as expected. And the template is defined in [index.js](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js#L71) - at [protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter) and it doesnt generate tabular report.

[image]

Change the template [here](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js#L71)in case you want to customize. I personally recommend [protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter)